# Cont Time Markov Chains. Stationary Probability

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

> A barber finishes haircuts at rate $3$, measured in hours, so on
>   average it takes him 20 minutes to cut a person’s hair. Customers
>   arrive at rate 2. There is, however, only a two chair waiting room.
>   When an arriving customer sees that both waiting room chairs are
>   taken, he leaves. What fraction of customers leave without a haircut
>   in the long run?

A state describes the total number of customers in the shop, so the state space is $S = [0, 1, 2,3]$
The detailed balance equations are:

$2\pi_0=3\pi_1$,$2\pi_1=3\pi_2$ and $2\pi_2=3\pi_3$

Can someone explain to me why are those the balance equations?

Then it's easy to simly use $\sum \pi_n=1$ to solve for waiting times.

Definition:
$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} p_{ij}(t)=\pi_j$

Answer (score 1):

The generator matrix is:

$$
     G= \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
        3 & -5 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 3 & -5 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 & -3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
The balance equations in vector form are: $\mathbf{\pi G = 0}$, so, working down each of the four columns in turn:

\begin{align}
-2\pi_0 + 3\pi_1 &= 0 \\
2\pi_0 - 5\pi_1 + 3\pi_2 &= 0 \\
2\pi_1 - 5\pi_2 + 3\pi_3 &= 0 \\
2\pi_2 - 3\pi_3 &= 0. \\
\end{align}

Some straightforward manipulation of these equations gives the ones you provided.